# Integrating payment gateway "Instamojo" in Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel-5.1, instamojo

I'm using a package 'IndiPay' (https://github.com/softon/indipay) in Laravel 5.1. I have configured api_key and auth_token in my .env file. And in the parameters list, included the required POST parameters (purpose and amount). Additionally, added tid with reference to the GitHub. Even though, I couldn't make the payment successful. It throwed an error like problem in Hash parameter. I attach my screenshot here.

[image]

Any suggestions please?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check whether you have included all the below parameters that I have listed. It could be that you would have missed out some required POST parameters.

```
 'txnid' => 'XXXX',
 'redirect_url' => 'XXXX',
 'purpose' => 'Testing',
 'amount' => 2500,
 'buyer_name' => 'XXX',
 'allow_repeated_payments' => <true/false>
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have missed out the buyer name in the parameter list.

Comment: Yes. It worked for me also now but the main site it shows only purpose and amount are mandatory fields.